# How do I stop Jenkins wiping a job's workspace (and thus private Maven repo)?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins I'm using private Maven repositories (local to the workspace) to avoid Maven repo concurrency issues.

I'm finding that Jenkins deletes this repo folder (`[jenkins home]/jobs/[job]/workspace/.repository`) every build, which is a pain as this means Maven downloads its whole universe of jars for every build.

I have checked my SCM (Accurev) plugin and modified its code so that it doesn't purge the workspace when starting a build. However, something else in Jenkins is still deleting the workspace.

I'm not using the Workspace Cleanup plugin or any similar.

**UPDATE: turns out I hadn't modified the Accurev plugin code properly. Re-visiting this was the solution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much tinkering I discovered the Accurev plugin was in fact still deleting my workspace after my code change to it.

I fixed my code. Jenkins no longer clears my whole workspace.

So - in conclusion, it's generally your SCM plugin that's deleting files from your job workspace.